# Append with input value with <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Thanks in advance.
I am trying to append a list using the input value. I can append a list using predefined string, and I can append using input value to non list item. But I'm having trouble combining these, it seems to add extra list items.
This is the code I'm using:

```
    <ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<form>
    <div><textarea class="example-default-value" id="example-textarea" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;">Type some text in here to be appended</textarea></div>
    <div><input type="button" value="Append" onclick="example_append()" /></div>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
$('.example-default-value').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
    $(this).blur(function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            this.value = default_value;
        }
    });
});
function example_append() {
    $('ol').append("<li>"+($('#example-textarea').val())+"<li>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you learn the native DOM API  before turning to something like jQuery. Also, you shouldn't use `onclick` inline event listeners, that is bad practice. Start using `addEventListener`.

Comment: @connexo thank you for your answer, I went back and learned some better practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont use jquery anywhere else you can use javascript for this function as following:

```js
function example_append() {
let textInput = document.getElementById("example-textarea");
if(textInput.value !==""){
    let node = document.createElement("LI");  
    node.innerHTML = textInput.value;
    textInput.value="";
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
  }else {
    alert("Enter something in textarea")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="myList">
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<form>
   <div>
    <textarea class="example-default-value" placeholder="Type here"
    id="example-textarea" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="button" value="Append"
    onclick="example_append()" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

OH OK I see - I'm using two li tags instead of one li and one /li closing tag! Oh dear... more coffee required!!

```
    function example_append() {
    $('ol').append("<li>"+($('#example-textarea').val())+"</li>");
}
```

Comment: more coffee is always fine:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the close tag for li in your example_append() function.

`$('ol').append("<li>"+($('#example-textarea').val())+"<li>");`

to

`$('ol').append("<li>"+($('#example-textarea').val())+"</li>");`